# Is Social Network Analysis or NER the best way to create a semantic graph?

Tags: text-mining, graph-theory, social-network

I am planning to create a semantic graph by creating an automatic ontology. I want to know which is the best process to do it.

1. Doing social network analysis to create people, relationships, likes, objects etc
   or
2. Carrying out Named Entiity Recognition, Relation extraction etc to extract people, relationships etc?

Can you outline me which is better and why, and if both arent the correct way, which is the better way?